# asp.net 2010 web service not working when web server image was moved to virtual environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I had a web server (win 2012 64b) on which I had Visual Studio 2010 installed and a Web Service developed in C# was configured.

It was working fine until our system engineer took the sever image using Acronis True Image and created a server in Virtual environment.

From then I keep getting the following errors when tried to access the web service from the newly established server in virtual environment:

- If IP is used to access:

  > System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.
  >   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
  >   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
  >   at WebReference.IMSWebService.getCompanies(String akey) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\carewebservice\2f497378\d40587f0\App_WebReferences.v12qtait.0.cs:line 270
  >   at MyWebService.getCompanies(String akey) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebService\App_Code\MyWebService.cs:line 36
- If full qualified domain name is used:

  > System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
  >   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
  >   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
  >   at WebReference.IMyCareWebService.getCompanies(String akey) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mywebservice\2f497378\d40587f0\App_WebReferences.uqcx8w8i.0.cs:line 270
  >   at MyWebService.getCompanies(String akey) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebService\App_Code\MyWebService.cs:line 36

Comment: What code is in the `MyWebService.cs` file near line 36?

Comment: 36:  return ICW.getDepartments("1" "mykey"));

I forgot to inform that when the system engineer moved the server to virtual environment, he changed the IP and the hostname of the web server.

Comment: i unjoined the server from domain and still the problem exist - i run a web application and it connects to a webservice, it works from the VS development environment but when run from the browser it give 503 error.

Comment: finally after a month i could solve the issue myself, i had to remove the following from the web config of the web service:
    <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://130.130.11.90:8080/" usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>